# Nodemailer returning authentication error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, postfix-mta

I have the following as my nodemailer script:

```
'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'localhost.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'user',
    pass: 'pass',
  }
});

module.exports = (msg) => {
  let { from, to, subject, html } = msg;
  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
    from,
    to,
    subject, // plain text body
    html,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
  });
}
```

When I try to run the function I receive the following error:

```
{ Error: 139970611431232:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:
code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }
```

I setup my postfix authentication using this guide if it matters: http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailservers.html

I do have my config setup for postfix to use port 465. Perhaps it's an issue with calling on localhost even though my postfix server is setup with the host being the domain to my website? I do have my postfix setup with ssl as well. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Update:
*I'm 90% sure this is an issue with the credentials I'm providing to nodemailer but I can't find out where the disconnect lies. The postfix server is working fine at sending messages on its own but not via a script. I've tried different ports and different config setups but I can't figure out what's going wrong and the error is not very helpful.*

This is my postfix main.cf file

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = 
btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permite_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = zacharyhill.xyz
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inter_protocols = all
```

Comment: `SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO: unknown protocol` indicates you that there is a problem with the secure connection, not with the `credentials`. `[...] Perhaps it's an issue with calling on localhost even though my postfix server is setup with the host being the domain to my website[...]`  do you use the real domain to connect or `127.0.0.1`, `localhost`or similar?

Comment: As in the connection is not configured correctly? I'm very new to ssl so tbh I'm pretty lost with this. Been racking my head on this same problem for a few days.

I am using localhost and not the domain or it cannot access the port

Comment: The first thing you should do is to test the connection using `openssl`. Test it with `openssl s_client -connect youdomain.tld:465` and `openssl s_client  -connect youdomain.tld:465 -starttls smtp` which one will or or if both will fail.

Comment: This is what I get...

$ openssl s_client -connect zacharyhill.xyz:465
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=111

$ openssl s_client -connect zacharyhill.xyz:465 - starttls smtp
unknown option -

Comment: Oh one moment. You only listen locally on the loopback interface with postfix? If so then do the same test using `127.0.0.1` on your server instead of the domain. Do you do this for testing before going live, because otherwise ssl would not make much sens. (Btw you by mistake added a space between `-` and `starttls`)

Comment: When the space is removed, I get the same error as the first command. And to be honest, I'm not sure on the listening to only the loopback interface.. I just followed a couple of guides to setup postfix and dovecot

Comment: You really should do much reading about how to setup a mail server, otherwise you will get real problems. Anyway, do the test with `127.0.0.1` while logged in on your server. To see if you listen only locally you can use `sudo netstat -plnt`  if `0.0.0.0:465`  is listed then you listen on all ips, if it is only `127.0.0.1:465` then you only listen locally.

Comment: The test works when run with 127.0.0.1. I'm confused as to what you are saying I should do with the netstat command but it does say "no peer certificate available" as well as "no client certificate ca names sent" when I connect. I can post the info returned. Here that is [github gist](https://gist.github.com/zhillb/78a1a94efba4560efb2c1e8d2aca0b82)

Comment: And what happens for `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:465 -starttls smtp` ?

Comment: Seems to give a slightly better response...
[github gist for -starttls smtp command](https://gist.github.com/zhillb/21ef788043da1a13bf5a3b43ea0fa3c8)

Comment: Your problem is not nodemailer but the setup of you server. Postfix seems to be configured to listens on port 465 as a non SSL connection that supports using a secure connection using TLS upgrade, you can confirm this by writing `telnet 127.0.0.1 25` if this shows something like `220 yourhost.tls ESMTP Postfix` then this is the case (you can exit the telnet session by typing `quit` and pressing enter). But `465` should be ssl only, only a connection to port `587` should behave as `465` does right now. And there seems to be something wrong with your certificate setup.

Comment: But this problem is off topic for StackOverflow, problems with the postfix setup should be asked on ServerFault.

Comment: As a note `465`, is not an official port for smtp, it is just support for legacy reasons, so you should use `587`.

Comment: And you should not ask duplicate questions or at least refer to it [Having an issue with nodemailer and postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511300/having-an-issue-with-nodemailer-and-postfix).